# How to generate <form> using DOM?

Tags: php

Can one use the php DOM class - http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php to generate form elements?.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that you couldn't?

Comment: I haven't seen an example yet,so i can't say much.

Comment: Yes, it can.  Have you tried it?  What issues were you having?

Comment: Edited the question with what i have done so far.

Comment: Does that code not work?  Do you get any errors?  What's the HTML it outputs?  What's the issue here?

Comment: Ummm... then what's the question?

Comment: @Rocket I was waiting for 8 hours before i could answer my own question.@downvoters not cool!.

Comment: @username002: You didn't say that that was your answer, when you added it your question.  You said that it was what you tried with no specification of whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and works.

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $html = $dom->createElement('html');
    $dom->appendChild($html);

    //head
    $head = $dom->createElement('head');
    $title = $dom->createElement('title');
    $title->nodeValue = "title of my page";
    $head->appendChild($title);
    $html->appendChild($head);


    //body
    $body = $dom->createElement('body');
    $h1 = $dom->createElement('h1');
    $h1->nodeValue = "Hello, World";
    $body->appendChild($h1);
    $html->appendChild($body);

    //form
    $form = $dom->createElement('form');
    $form->setAttribute("action", "");
    $form->setAttribute("method", "post");

   $checkbox = $dom->createElement("input");
   $checkbox->setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
   $checkbox->setAttribute("name", "myCheckbox");
   $checkbox->setAttribute("value", "someval");
   $form->appendChild($checkbox);

   $body->appendChild($form);

    echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

Comment: Sure, you can shoot yourself in the foot. I think that generating presentation layer in this OOP style is a bad practice